# Is it possible to dump the properties/methods of a type userdata variable?

Tags: lua, user-data, metatable, lua-userdata

Hi I'm wanting to get all the properties and methods of a type function that returns userdata. The documentation on the API i'm using is quite poor, and I know there are more stuff not documented.

```
local w = gui.CreateWindow(...) -- "returns userdata"
```

I would like to loop over `w` and get all it's functions and properties

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no general mechanism to do this. If the userdata instance you get back has a [metatable](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.4), you can retrieve it and browse/navigate, as you'd do for a regular table.

If it's ffi-based userdata, you can get some additional information using ffi.typeinfo (see [ffi-reflect](https://github.com/corsix/ffi-reflect) and [parseback](https://github.com/javierguerragiraldez/parseback) for modules that use that).